# Oscillating mesh movement

Tags: openfoam

I want to run a simulation in which the DTCHull mesh oscillates left and right in a sinusoidal manner across the water, as is shown in this diagram (Oldfield et. al. 2015):
[image: Oldfield et. al. 2015]
How would I do this with interDyMFoam? I've seen examples in which rigid-body behaviour is simulated with dynamic meshes (e.g. floatingObject). However, what I need here is to have plain prescribed motion.

Comment: Could you please advise us whether the answer helps, or if not, which aspects should be improved?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this end, `overInterDyMFoam` from [OpenFOAM-v1712](https://www.openfoam.com) (starting from OpenFOAM-v1706) can be used alongside the `prescribed rigid body motion` functionality.

`overInterDyMFoam` is the `interDyMFoam` using [overset mesh](https://www.openfoam.com/releases/openfoam-v1706/numerics.php) functionality wherein mesh deformation in the latter is replaced by the [Chimera grid concept](http://celeritassimtech.com/?page_id=15).

Considering no set-up was mentioned in your question and therefore further settings can't be recommended on top of them, I can suggest the following tutorials for a model development from scratch:

- `tutorials/multiphase/overInterDyMFoam/floatingBody` for `overInterDyMFoam` settings, and
- `tutorials/incompressible/pimpleDyMFoam/oscillatingInletACMI2D` for prescribed `oscillatingLinearMotion` settings (Might be other tutorials regarding this).